# Working with Laravel 4 repository and my own repository

Tags: git, laravel, repository

I have a big question... how to work with two repositories in my project? Because alread cloned the Laravel 4 repository and I need to add the origin of my own project repository.

I need to use both repositories because my own repository will have the laravel framework and my application, and the laravel repository because if exist new changes, can update to the new version... or exists another way to do this.

**Note: ** When I try to add the origin of my own repository to the folder when cloned the laravel repository says:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Origin already exists, you can rename it:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

And then add yours.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall.git
```

After that you can push to yours

```
git push origin master
```

or downaload from Laravel's

```
git pull upstream develop
```

Comment: Thanks...  but after add my repository.. how can check the new files?.. because if I type git status can't see all laravel repository files that I need to push of my repository.